# The introduction of a new variable made my coefficient of interest flip sings : what can I say about correlation?

Tags: correlation, least-squares

I am currently studying the relationship between academic freedom (independant variable) and university rankings (dependant variable) using OLS. Each individual is a university, and my variables (except for rank) are at the country level. I clustered standard errors by country. Here are my results :

[image]

With the base model, with just Rank and Academic freedom, I observe a negative significant coefficient (a negative coefficient means that greater academic freedom gives you better rankings, since the lower ranking you have, the closer you are to the 1st place). When I introduce a measure of the Rule of Law in my model (to tackle the problem of omitted variable bias), the coefficient of academic freedom becomes positive and significant.

What exactly can I deduce about correlation between Academic freedom and university ranking in this example ? Can I make any interpretation about what the "true" correlation between my variables is (positive or negative), or would I need more information ?

What explains the change of coefficient here ? Is it because I corrected for omitted variable bias, or is it due to something else entirely ?

Comment: *What exactly can I deduce about correlation in this example ?* Correlation between what?

Comment: *What explains the change of coefficient here ? Is it because I corrected for omitted variable bias...* Changing the model very often changes coefficient values, but it's not possible to say as a general rule whether the change arising from adding a predictor represents an improvement or not. It depends on the nature of the relationship between the variables involved. The field of causal inference deals with these problems a lot and discusses them using DAGs. That may be worth looking at.

Comment: To your first question : correlation between academic freedom and university rankings. I wanted to know if this gives me information as to whether the correlation is positive or negative. For your second answer, what does "DAG" refer to ?

Comment: Directed Acyclic Graph